# how to stop scrollview scrolling when scroll the child view which is a webview

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have a webview which is a child view of a scrollView.

I found that if you scrolled the webview, the scrollview would be scrolled too at the same time in Android, so I'd like to set the "scrollingEnabled" of scrollView as "fasle" when I started to touch the scrollview then set it as "true" when my touch end.

But I found that 'touchend' event was not fired when you scroll it.

Hope someone could help me to solve this, thanks.

```
if(OS_ANDROID){
    $.webview.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
        Ti.API.info("webview touchstart");
        $.s_1.scrollingEnabled = false;
    });

    $.webview.addEventListener('touchend', function(){
        Ti.API.info("webview touchend");
        $.s_1.scrollingEnabled = true;
    });

    $.webview.addEventListener('touchcancel', function(){
        Ti.API.info("webview touchcancel");
        $.s_1.scrollingEnabled = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @jack,

  Have you found the solution for the above ? Because I'm also stuck with the same issue now.

Comment: Hi Jack, I tried like below  disable the scroll on webview's touchstart & Enable the scroll on scrollview's touchend , so that the webview's touchend( this event will also trigger scrollview's touch end) will enable the scroll


`
$.condWebView.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
  $.conditionScrollView.setScrollingEnabled(false);
});`


`
$.conditionScrollView.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
  $.conditionScrollView.setScrollingEnabled(true);
});`

Seems like some what better

Comment: only handling the touchstart on webview  is not enough, Need to handle all events


`wv.addEL('click', wvHandler);`
`wv.addEL('dblclick', wvHandler);`
`wv.addEL('doubletap', wvHandler);`
`wv.addEL('longclick', wvHandler);`
`wv.addEL('longpress', wvHandler);`
`wv.addEL('pinch', wvHandler);`
`wv.addEL('singletap', wvHandler);`
`wv.addEL('swipe', wvHandler);`
`wv.addEL('touchmove', wvHandler);`
`wv.addEL('touchstart', wvHandler);`
`wv.addEL('twofingertap', wvHandler);`

`function wvHandler(e) {
  $.sv.setScrollingEnabled(false);
};`


PS: addEventListener is mentioned by addEL